# bun: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by bun)

Tags: javascript, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bun

I am trying to install bun to wsl and have already added

```
BUN_INSTALL="/home/jack/.bun"
```

and

```
PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

to

```
$HOME/.bashrc
```

and when I do bun -v the error shows up.

Comment: it doesn't work on WSL, its still WIP.

Comment: I have seen a lot of tutorials using it in WSL like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-deAm_7akK4&t=399s

Comment: I saw other video, where he couldn't make it work on WSL. Here follow [this](https://github.com/Jarred-Sumner/bun/issues/255#issuecomment-1176900771) issue.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to upgrade your WSL Ubuntu version. A version that works with Bun is 22.04.

You can check your current version inside a Ubuntu terminal: `lsb_release -a`

To update:

1. Go to "Microsoft Store" in the start menu for Windows 10/11.
2. Download Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Then proceed to reinstall Bun:

1. `sudo apt install unzip`
2. `curl https://bun.sh/install | bash`

There's a post about it [here](https://www.torsive.com/2022/07/installing-bun-js-on-windows-1011-with.html)